# calculate the limit of the sequence, given by a general term.

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate the limit of the sequence, given by a general term.

$2.61$

**$ u_n =\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}}{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{3^n}} $**

ok, I didn't expect I will get stuck on this exercise, but well I am only a beginner and I know that I don't know nothing and need to improve. To be honest, the answer from book is $\frac{4}{3}$ but I got during my calculations $\frac{3}{2}$
I mean I have this:

$a_n=a_1q^{n-1}$

so I get in the counter:

$a_n=1*(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}=(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$

and I get in the denominator
$a_n=(\frac{1}{3})^{n-1} $

so I was thinking it is easy but it did not get a result like in my book, so I was wondering where did I fail.

$u_n= \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}}{(\frac{1}{3})^{n-1}}$

what should I do now? Because I get result $\frac{3}{2}$ so it must be wrong.
In general something divided by a fraction needs to be multiplied by the inverse of the expression.. so I did mess up something, or my way of thinking is wrong? Can someone help me figure out, how to get proper result from my book ($\frac{4}{3}$).

Comment: Why not to use formula of sum of geometrical progression in nominator and denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $n$ goes to $\infty$, the top and bottom sums are $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{n}}$, respectively. Evaluating those geometric series, we get them to equal $\frac{\frac{1}{2^{0}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 2$ and $\frac{\frac{1}{3^{0}}}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{3}{2}$, respectively. Therefore $\frac{2}{3/2} = 4/3$.